# remove file extension htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

the following code is not working to remove the file extension .php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

my url not changing from `example/about.php` to `example.com/about`

Comment: You sure you know how rewriting works? It does _not_ magically change the links inside a web page you send out. It processes _incoming_ requests. If you want to change the address in the browser, then you need the redirect flag `[R]` to make it send a second request.

Comment: im new to htaccess rewrite. could you tel me how to rewrite the url by removing the .php extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the answer. Its working. the code is as follows to rewrite and redirect the url

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

It rewrites and redirects the URL. Thanks all for ur answers.

Comment: After looking into a lot of references, only this one helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

This RewriteRule should remove the `.php` extension from a request. Try placing it before your RewriteConds.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R]
```

Comment: after correction it says `The requested URL /example/var/chroot/home/content/71/10295671/html/example/about was not found on this server.`

Comment: Could you try it with a leading slash?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: the url is not changing in the address bar.@RaGu

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```