# .htaccess to remove .php extenssion in not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

Before posting here I've tried solutions [URL1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113410/remove-file-extension-htaccess-not-working), [URL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628001/removing-html-url-extension-using-htaccess-not-working) but not fixed yet. My `.htaccess` code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

In my application `$_GET` and `$_POST` used and file structure in `htdocs` like this:

`shopping ->(main folder)
          css(folder)
          images(folder)
          js(folder)
          .htaccess
          file1.php
          file2.php
           :
           :
          file9.php`

So how I can get rid from removing `.php` in URL

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that `.htaccess` is applied in the first place — [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running);
2. Make sure that your configuration allows overriding at least `FileInfo` in `.htaccess` files (you may also do `AllowOverride All`):

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www/html">
       AllowOverride FileInfo
   </Directory>
   ```

   See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache) for details.